# Paramagnetic liquids at room temperature

Tags: magnetism, liquids

So as most inorganic liquids are diamagnetic at room temperature (like water), what are some applications to paramagnetic liquids at room temperature?

Answer (score 3):

One way to generate a paramagnetic liquid is to use an active metal to generate solvated electrons. [Burrows et al.[1]](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.abk3099) describe a solution of lithium in ethylenediamine plus tetrahydrofuran, which can be used in Birch reductions at ambient conditions without handling liquid ammonia.

**Reference**

JAMES BURROWS, SHOGO KAMO, AND KAZUNORI KOIDE (2021). "Scalable Birch reduction with lithium and ethylenediamine in tetrahydrofuran". *Science* **374**, 741-746. DOI:10.1126/science.abk3099